# problem with XMLHttpRequest.statusText after IIS hardening

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis

net web api and I have a custom filter class called `AuthorizeLoginApi` from here I have some condition and returning the data based on the condition for example if the condition is not satisfied the user will receive one of the message from below code:

```
actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage()
{
    ReasonPhrase = "Error",
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
    Content = new StringContent("Token is not assigned to the logged in user")
};

actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage()
{
    ReasonPhrase = "RefreshToken",
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
    Content = new StringContent(data)
};

actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage()
{
    ReasonPhrase = "AdminSupport",
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
    Content = new StringContent("Something went wrong please contact administrator!")
};

actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage()
{
    ReasonPhrase = "CheckUserAction",
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
    Content = new StringContent("You are not authorized to use this option!")
};

actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage()
{
    ReasonPhrase = "IsLoggedIn",
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
    Content = new StringContent("Not logged in or session expired.")
};
```

in my `$.ajax` i am handling this like below

```
error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
    const errorThrown = XMLHttpRequest.statusText;
    switch (errorThrown) {
        case 'IsLoggedIn':
        case 'Error':
            Utils.showError(XMLHttpRequest.responseText, function () { redirectToURL() });
            break;
        case 'AdminSupport':
            Utils.showError(XMLHttpRequest.responseText, function () { });
            break;
        case 'CheckUserAction':
            if (hideShowElem == undefined) {
                Utils.showAlert('You are not authorized to use this option!', '', function () {
                    if (hasValue($("#CommonIndex").val())) {
                        if (hasValue(window.parent.$('.k-window-content.k-content.k-window-iframecontent').data('kendoWindow'))) {
                            window.parent.$('.k-window-content.k-content.k-window-iframecontent').data('kendoWindow').close();
                        }
                        window.location.href = $("#CommonIndex").val();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                hideShowElem(XMLHttpRequest);
            }
            break;
        case 'Unauthorized':
            Utils.isLoggedIn(function () {
                ajaxCallFunction(apiType, apiUrl, dataObject, successCallBack);
            }, function () {
                Utils.showError("Not logged in or session expired.", function () {
                    if (hasValue(window.parent.$('.k-window-content.k-content.k-window-iframecontent').data('kendoWindow'))) {
                        window.parent.$('.k-window-content.k-content.k-window-iframecontent').data('kendoWindow').close();
                    }
                    redirectToURL();
                });
            });
            break;
        case 'Forbidden'://this case is coming from my (rate filters)
            Utils.showError(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            break;
        default:
            if (hideShowElem != undefined) {
                hideShowElem(XMLHttpRequest);
            }
            break;
    }
    Utils.showProgress(false);
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
    $('#gd-modal-spinner').hide();
}
```

and it is working fine in our (development, test) environment and even on every clients server except one of our client who just did IIS hardening.

at their server `XMLHttpRequest.statusText` is always coming as error and `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` is not coming as per the error.

I don't understand what should be done here

Comment: Is it output statusText normally but responseText error? So are you getting any error message or is the XMLHttpRequest not working as expected on the client after IIS hardening? Please provide more detailed error information. Also, you can use FRT to generate logs in IIS to locate the cause.